# Drying floam for sculpting

Tags: sculpting

I'm looking for a floam recipe that will dry to a relative sturdy shape. I'm working on a puppet and I want to rough out the dimensions and proportions, and I want something cheap and light-weight. If the quality is high enough, I might just use it for the final build, but for now, I basically want to 'sketch' in three-dimensions.

I've found a number of [floam recipes](http://parentingchaos.com/diy-floam/) on the web, but they are aimed at kids' entertainment, so they are advertised as basically non-drying when sealed away. I want one that dries, so that I don't deform the shape when I'm done with it.

Can someone offer a floam recipe that dries, and will be sturdy enough to carry around once finished?

Comment: If it's non-drying when sealed up, doesn't that mean it will dry out if left out? Play-doh is non-drying when sealed but dries when left out.

Comment: @Catija I guess the answer is yes. But, if it dries slowly, it might slump and deform due to gravity as it dries over days. I'm looking for a go-to recipe, not a "try it and find out"

Answer (score 4):

According to [this link](http://www.miniscience.com/kits/slime/), adding more borax, starch or talcum powder will make the slime more rigid.  Also kneading the slime repeatedly with dry hands will extract moisture, further adding to the slime's ability to maintain its shape while air drying.

Answer (score 2):

Insulation foam expands to fill and has the qualities of lightness, rigidity, and low cost.  I believe it is also paintable. The drawbacks are messiness and the need to contain the foam.

Were you planning to carve features?  If so, then simply fill a paper or styro foam cup, let dry and go to it.

You could also model a face in clay then make a two part plaster mold.  Remember to size the inside of the mold and apply a release, then fill the void with insulation foam.  No carving and the possibility of an army of puppets.

I hope I haven't overreached here, as I am not familiar with the "floam" material.  Please forgive any indiscretion.